# "Data directory /var/lib/postgresql/13/main must not be owned by root"

Tags: apt, kali-linux, android, postgresql, arm64

I encounter the below problem:

```
└─$ sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y 

[sudo] password for kali: Hit:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InR
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done 
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it. 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
Calculating upgrade... Done 
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: exfat-fuse gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio libidn11 librest-0.7-0 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. 
The following packages will be upgraded: postgresql-13 1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 664 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/14.7 MB of archives. After this operation, 106 kB of additional disk space will be used. 
Preconfiguring packages ... Setting up libss2:arm64 (1.46.4-1) ... (Reading database ... 255637 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-13_13.4-2_arm64.deb ... invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel 
Stopping PostgreSQL 13 database server: mainError: Data directory /var/lib/postgresql/13/main must not be owned by root ... failed! failed! 
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed. dpkg: warning: old postgresql-13 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1 
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ... 
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel Stopping PostgreSQL 13 database server: main
Error: Data directory /var/lib/postgresql/13/main must not be owned by root ... failed! failed! invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed. 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-13_13.4-2_arm64.deb (--unpack): new postgresql-13 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1 
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-13_13.4-2_arm64.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What did I miss?

Comment: You also missed that Kali isn't meant for this, at least, not for users who can't diagnose apt issues. I wish stackexchange would ban kali linux questions flat out because kali isn't meant for newbies who don't get what kali is, it's that darned mr. robot, but keep in mind, he wasn't sitting around upgrading his kali, he was using it correctly, as an expert hacker/cracker, not confusing it with debian testing. I'd say at least 99% of kali questions here simply demonstrate the user shouldn't be trying to run kali. Adopting a strategy more like openbsd uses to handle newbie users would be good.

Comment: Might want to read: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/3976

Answer (score 4):

This thread is not properly labeled, the top answer completely wrong, and the correct answer (JP's) is missing a step. This problem is with Kali Nethunter (mobile) on arm64, it is still a problem and it happens on all arm64 phones. I encountered this issue when I was installing Nethunter Rootless 2022.2 via Termux on some old devices that I had.

Something to note is that this package is not important if you are installing Nethunter rootless, because as far as I'm aware rootless does not have support for any of the features that postgresql is used for. But if you want to fix it...

All you need to do is run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

Now run this, you HAVE to run these together or it will not work:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql* && dpkg --configure -a
```

You need to run this again to upgrade the package

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

OP was not being a total n00b when the chown command wasn't working, it was the first thing I tried when this issue came up and it was so weird that I went looking for threads on it. I checked the /var/lib/postgresql directory with the default kali user and the root user before even using the chown command and the owner of the directory always matched the user I was logged in as, and chown did not change this. I then check /etc/passwd to see if postgres was even a user, but it was there and everything was correct. I don't know why the cli is displaying different owners for the same file, I would guess that maybe it's weird unrooted-android file-priv stuff, but the 3 commands above will fix the upgrading problem. Fixing this will be important if you are installing Nethunter Lite or the kali kernel.

Comment: I was experiencing the exact issue as you described. Not sure why folks commenting around other answers have to be so rude. To anyone else - this is the most robust and intelligent answer that I've read so far in this post. Also take into account the kernel + ARM architecture as pointed out. Certain devices are not officially supported and may run into strange issues like this. The explanation here & steps outlined in this answer worked for me with flying colors.

Comment: Great answer tho...not sure for the need for others to be rude....it seems easier to ignore....well...from my pov

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
PostgreSQL 13 database server: mainError: Data directory /var/lib/postgresql/13/main must not be owned by root
```

In a freshly updated Kali VM (downloaded from Kali website) the group and owner of /var/lib/postgresql/13/main shows:

```
drwx------ 19 postgres postgres 4096 Sep  5 16:30 main
```

Don't know if simply chowning the directory to postgres:postgres would resolve it, but I don't believe it'd hurt either :-)

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/13/main
```

Comment: /The following command did not change:  ˋˋˋ┌──(kali㉿localhost)-[~]                                └─$ sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/                                                                                                                                                                                                            ┌──(kali㉿localhost)-[~]                                └─$ ls -hl /var/lib/postgresql/13/                      total 3.5K                                              drwx------. 19 kali kali 3.5K May 19 23:54 mainˋˋˋ What did I miss?

Comment: I'd first sudo su to become actual root, then try chown again - sometimes that's worked when plain sudo fails. That failing, I'd try changing the group ownership with chgrp then chown again. That failing I'm out of ammo. As I'm using a VM prepared by Kali ppl themselves, I can only compare what a proper installation looks like to yours. I can only guess you've accidentally done something funky when installing, as the group:owner shows incorrectly as "Kali". But having such a basic issue as incorrect permissions makes me suspect there might be a deeper issue lurking below.

Comment: Now, I got ''''drwx------. 19 root root 3.5K May 19 23:54 main''' and error remained.

Comment: Wait what? What exactly did you do? If you chown for foo:fii and group:user shows root:root, something's seriously wrong.

Comment: # chown -R foo:fii /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/       chown: invalid user: ‘foo:fii’

Answer (score 2):

Everybody starts somewhere. Kali is just another distro. This might help. https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/mqay2w/kali_android_rootless_upgrade_issues/

Seems postgresql blocks installation, you can unblock it by doing:

```
              rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql*postinst
```

after running above command:

```
              dpkg --configure -a
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
              rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql* && dpkg --configure -a
```

With this, you will wipe postgresql package metadata, specifically file lists and md5sums. Package still would be visible, as status file is not part of info. But when you attempt to uninstall the package, the actual contents will not be uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

This one seemed to of worked for me, so far atleast.

```
rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql* && dpkg --configure -a
```

I only just done it so fingers crossed its stays ok now. It only worked after doing

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

as kali
and then

```
sudo su

rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql* && dpkg --configure -a
        
      and

apt update && apt full-upgrade -y
      as root
```

i still had an error until i ran

`su kali`

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y


    As kali again
```